# $M=\{x\in E: T_n(x) \text{ is cauchy}\}$ We need to show $M$ is a closed set.

Tags: functional-analysis

$E,F$ be complex or real normed linear space, $T_n:E\rightarrow F$ be a sequence of continous linear transformation such that $\sup_n||T_n||<\infty$. Let $$M=\{x\in E: T_n(x) \text{ is cauchy}\}$$ We need to show $M$ is a closed set. I just need a hint now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_k) \in M$ be a sequence converging to some $x \in E$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and $K>0$ such that $\sup\limits_{n \geq 1} \| T_n \| < K$.

Chose $k \geq 1$ such that $\| x-x_k \|< \epsilon/4K$ and then $N \geq 1$ such that $n,m \geq N$ implies $\| T_n(x_k)-T_m(x_k) \| <\epsilon/2$. For $n,m \geq N$, $$\begin{array}{lcl} \|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\| & \leq & \|T_n(x)-T_n(x_k)\| + \|T_n(x_k)-T_m(x_k)\|+ \| T_m(x_k)-T_m(x) \| \\ \\ & \leq & 2K \| x-x_k\| + \| T_m(x_k)-T_n(x_k)\| \leq \epsilon \end{array}$$ Thus $x \in M$, and a fortiori $M$ is closed.